# How could I do the same thing using asp.net and jquery instead of php?

Tags: php, asp.net, jquery

The author in this screencast is using jquery to submit data to a database using php.  The link is here:

http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-day-13/

How could I do the same thing using asp.net and sql server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the jQuery AJAX query is doing is quite simple. It's just sending a request to a url. Be it static (http://example.com/ajax.aspx) or relative (ajax.aspx)

You can send POST or GET data with that request and it will function just like if a form sent that information.

Comment: The author just creates a php script in the page.  What is the alternative I would use for asp.net?

Comment: I believe you use Request.QueryString("Foo"); if you send a GET and Request.Form("Foo"); if you send a POST to get the info you send with jQuery AJAX